# LiveData initialization

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

I have 2 live data objects in my `ViewModel`:

```
private val _myData : LiveData<String> = myRepository.getData()
val myDataAvailable: LiveData<Boolean> = _myData.map { it != null }
```

As long as the repo doesn't issue a value, myDataAvailable will not be initialised. What is the best practice to set the initial value for `myDataAvailable` to false?

Comment: It seems like `myDataAvailable` is not useful in the first place. Since you’re working with LiveData, you need to observe it to properly react to the values, but it would be super clumsy to observe two different LiveData and try to get them to interact in your UI layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `liveData` builder function:

```
val myDataAvailable: LiveData<Boolean> = liveData {
        emit(false) 
        emitSource(_myData.map { it != null })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation for [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) says there is a [setValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#setvalue) method you can use to set the value.  Just make sure you call that on the object with the initial value before it gets returned by your repository.

Comment: Sorry, MutableLiveData was wrong. I corrected the initial post.

Comment: Your repository is still probably creating a MutableLiveData.  Set the initial value in there.  You can't do it *after* it's been cast to a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) because the setValue method is protected.